# what is instance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Recently I try to learn design pattern in JavaScript. So I choose Singleton Pattern as my first pattern. But the problem is when I read this code.

```
var Singleton = (function () {

    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function run() {

    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));  
}
```

I just wonder what is instance in JavaScript. It seems every object has its instance. Can I image that as constructor?

Comment: In this case, instance is just the name of a variable and is just used in the specific implementation of the pattern you're working with.

Comment: By definition a singleton only has one instance. This is stored by `var instance` and created only once by `createInstance`

Comment: So instance is “unique “variable in the global object?

Comment: Your *actual question* is unclear to me, possibly in part due to a language barrier. What do you mean when you say "*why is instance in JavaScript*" and "*what is instance in JavaScript*"? Why are you confused by the code? It does (if you actually call `run()`) what it's expected to do, non?

Comment: Instance is new Object this action for me at begins. But in this case. It seems like unique variable in the global object. So I am so confused.

Comment: Maybe I find the point. This sentence new Object("I am the instance"). So I wanna know what’s the instance actual is in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a class like this

```
Car { 
      var color, 
      var model, 
      var property
}
```

when you declare one new Car you're creating a new instance of your class Car, in other words, you're creating on "memory" (this is not always truth) a new space for a new object Car.

Imagine now that in your project you only need one Car and this Car will be the same all the time.
If you want to be sure that you only have one car you need to use a Singleton Pattern.

**How it works?**

The singleton pattern makes the constructor private and instead of access to the constructor of a class you should access to a "getInstance" method, this method check if any class earlier create a Car (returning to the example) if it is true returns the same instance previously created of the Car if it is false create a new Car.

Answer (score 0):

**`instance` in this case is just a variable that stores an instance of `Object`** which is trapped inside the closure, only accessible via `getInstance`.

```
var Singleton = (function () {

    // 2. `instance` gets defined with value `undefined`
    var instance;

    // 3. `createInstance` gets declared inside the closure
    function createInstance() {
        // 8. `createInstance` creates an instance of `Object` and returns it
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    // 4. The closure returns an object with getInstance, and gets assigned to `Singleton`
    return {
        getInstance: function () {

            // 6. Check if `instance` refers to something
            if (!instance) {
                // 7. Which it doesn't, so it calls `createInstance` and assigns it to `instance`
                // where `instance` is the variable declared in the closure in step 2
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            // 9. Return whatever is assigned to `instance`
            // 11. since `instance` already points to something, return it
            return instance;
        }
    };

// 1. This function executes immediately
})();

function run() {

    // 5. `getInstance` is called and assigned to instance1
    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();

    // 10. `getInstance` is called again and assigns whatever is returned to instance2
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    // instance1 === instance2 because `getInstance` returned the same thing.
    alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));  
}
```

Comment: I am so confused. Is instance just a variable or new Object this action?

Answer (score -1):

Instance is nothing but an object that you create out of a constructor function in javascript. Javascript does not have anything called class, but you can create functions which behave like a class. You can instantiate objects out of this function by invoking it using the "new" keyword. Here is an example for you:

```
function class {
    this.name = 'John';
}

var instance = new class();
alert(instance.name); // this alerts "John"
```

Now Singleton class always returns the same instance irrespective of the number of times you instantiate objects out of this class.